# Is there an equivalent to typedef in Transact-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Is there any way of aliasing datatypes in T-SQL (SQL Server 2005), a bit like a C typedef? I'd like to be able to alias, say, VARCHAR(20) as 'my_datatype' so that wherever I wish to use VARCHAR(20) I could instead use my_datatype.

Synonyms allow you to do this sort of thing for tables, and there are built-in synonyms for some datatypes too, but AFAICS it is not possible to define your own datatype synonyms. Anyone know any different?

Comment: Thanks very much for your answers -- I was too hung up on searching for the word 'typedef' to find the answer I was looking for in the tsql docs!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about this

```
CREATE TYPE  [schema_name.]typename
FROM system_data_type_name [(precision,scale)] [NULL|NOT NULL]
```

For example

```
CREATE TYPE CountryCode
FROM char(2) NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is [User Defined Datatypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007%28SQL.90%29.aspx), or UDD's.

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server 2005, you have [alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189283%28SQL.90%29.aspx) and [CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186366(SQL.90).aspx) types. Both use [CREATE TYPE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

CREATE TYPE perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

For PostgreSQL the syntax is a bit different:

```
CREATE DOMAIN  [schema_name.]new_typename
AS existing_typename [any_constraint];
```

For example:

```
CREATE DOMAIN CountryCode
AS char(2);
```